# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string ... is not a valid utf-8 string

Tags: php, web-services, soap, encoding, zend-framework

Hi I have a web service built using the Zend Framework. One of the methods is intended to send details about an order. I ran into some encoding issue. One of the values being returned contains the following:

**Jaime Torres Bodet #322-A Col. Lomas de Santa María**

The webservice is returning the following fault:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string 'Jaime Torres Bodet #322-A Col. Lomas de Santa Mar\xc3...' is not a valid utf-8 string</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How should I go about this problem?

Thanks

---

Followup: Problem was due to a truncated string by the database. The field was set to VARCHAR(50) and it truncated exactly in the middle of the encoded value.

Comment: @isherwood, I don't see where the asker declared that their problem was due to truncation.  How do you know this to be the case?  Was a comment from the asker deleted?

Comment: Are you asking me about an edit I made 4 years ago? My best guess is that I interpreted the preceding edit by OP as an answer posted as an update on the question. If I was wrong, fine, but it's a bit absurd to call me out all this time later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Today I run into same problem - the code which caused that problem was:

```
$request->Text = substr($text, 0, 40);
```

changing substr to mb_substr seems to solve the issue:

```
$request->Test = mb_substr($text, 0, 40, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score 18):

What about change the encoding settings:

SERVER:

```
$server = new SoapServer("some.wsdl", array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1')); // for 'windows-1252' too
```

CLIENT:

```
$server = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1')); // for 'windows-1252' too
```

... then the conversion is done automatically to UTF-8, I had the similiar problem, so this helped me, so it is tested

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that í != i. Try to convert your string to UTF-8 before using in a request. It may look like that:

```
$string = iconv('windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $string);
```

See http://php.net/iconv

Comment: Fair enough but I want to be able to send í and not convert it to i ...  because it is a mexican address.

Comment: It will be send as í, but in UTF-8 encoding, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

The answers above lead me to try:

```
// encode in UTF-8
$string = utf8_encode($string);
```

which also resolved the error for me.

Reference: [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a problem like this using [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) with [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive) to walk into my POST parameters, named *$params* (array).

Maybe this is useful for you:

```
array_walk_recursive($params,function (&$item){
    $item = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'UTF-8');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my case not the encoding of strings was the problem but that the file itself was not saved as UTF-8. Even explicit saving with UTF-8 encoding did not help.

For me it worked to insert a comment with an UTF-8 character like 
`// Å`