# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '\xa3...' is not a valid utf-8 string

Tags: php, soap, encoding

I'm trying to pass data from my mySQL database to a 3rd party web service which is on a Windows platform using SoapClient in PHP however if I send a field containing a pound sign (£) then I get an error saying:

SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '\xa3...' is not a valid utf-8 string

I assume it's something to do with the character encoding, am I right in thinking if I wrap utf8_encode() around each field this will fix the problem? I've just tried this from my end and I no longer get the error but can't check it at the 3rd party end until tomorrow as I don't have access right now.

Comment: I had same problem today and it solved by issue with utf8_encode();

Comment: Can you verify it worked??

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks like the same: [SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string ... is not a valid utf-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006274/soap-error-encoding-string-is-not-a-valid-utf-8-string)

I propose to use mb_substr instead of substr or you can set mbstring_overload to 2 or more in your php.ini. It should help you.