# SOAP-ERROR string is not a valid utf-8 for repeated characters

Tags: php, soap

This is very much related to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006274/soap-error-encoding-string-is-not-a-valid-utf-8-string). However, the issue is not the type of chars but the number it was occurred. I was able to fix the error based on that link but instead of displaying the right chars, it shows "?" instead. Let me show you my use cases:

**Case 1**: 
String: ❤️❤️❤️ 
Result: ❤️❤️?

**Case 2**: 
String:

> 字漢漢漢漢漢;
>   ，。《》”～@#¥%…&*（）
>   ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️

Result:

```
字漢漢漢?</Message4>
                    <Message5>??漢;，。《》”～@#¥%?</Message5>
                    <Message6>??&amp;*（）❤️❤️❤️?</Message6>
                    <Message7>?️❤️❤️</Messag
```

All characters was converted to utf-8, some of the chars will display properly, some won't. 
Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I would say it is due to encoding missmatches. Are you sure the source of the message is encoding in utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

1. You're trying to encode what *looks* like it might be a variation of Unicode, into UTF-8, so you're gonna run into some problems.
2. Take a really long look at the tool you are using to do the conversion, there are many way to convert between character encodings, and none of them are 100%.
3. Welcome to the wonderful world of the [nightmare that is character encoding](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/Character-sets-and-content-encoding-hell).

(your issue has absolutely nothing to do with the other stackoverflow issue you referenced.)

#### Encoding Extracted into Hex values

Your unencoded Heart:

```
E2 9D A4    EF B8 8F         heart   variation-selector
E2 9D A4    EF B8 8F         heart   variation-selector
E2 9D A4    EF B8 8F         heart   variation-selector
```

After conversion to UTF-8:

```
E2 9D A4    EF B8 8F         heart   variation-selector
E2 9D A4    EF B8 8F         heart   variation-selector
3F                           question-mark
```

The important thing to note here, is that this is a single character, made from [combining characters](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) (specifically, [variation selectors](https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F?lang=en)) of three-byte UTF-8 characters. Translation: it's probably (*I say probably because I can't know the source encoding*) three, two-character letters, being combined into one. Due to the nature of encoding hell, it is also possible that you copy-pasted a CJK character varation of [钤](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/94a4) but SO converted it to UTF-8.

Ultimately, you're going to have to be more specific with your encoding conversion. Best by using [PHP mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php), and at least adjusting php.ini with the following setting: `mbstring.substitute_character = "none"`

## The ?

Most encoding tools have a default behavior of replacing unknown characters with a question, square, or diamond. That's what's happening here. Whatever tool you're using in PHP is using the question-mark to say, "I don't know how to do three combined character like this, I give up."

**Good luck, you'll need it.**